# ASP.NET Equivalent to this cURL command

Tags: c#, asp.net, curl

I'm working with the Twilio API and it provides examples in PHP and Ruby. I'm working on a site to send text messages through the API that's coded in ASP.NET MVC 3, and using my limited knowledge of the WebRequest object, I was able to translate this:

```
curl -X POST 'https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/AC4840da0d7************f98b20b084/SMS/Messages.xml' \
-d 'From=%2B14155992671' \
-u AC4840da0d7************f98b20b084:f7fc2**************75342
```

Into this:

```
var request =
WebRequest.Create(MessageApiString + "?From=+14*********1&To=" + Phone + "&Body=" + smsCampaign.Message);

var user = "AC4840da0d7************f98b20b084";
var pass = "f7fc2**************75342";

string credentials = String.Format("{0}:{1}", user, pass);
request.Headers.Add("Authorization", credentials);

var result = request.GetResponse();
```

But it's not authenticating, I'm getting a 401 from their API. What is the equivalent C# to the cURL `-u` command?

**Update**

```
        var request =
            WebRequest.Create(MessageApiString + "?From=+14155992671&To=" + Phone + "&Body=" + smsCampaign.Message);

        var cc = new CredentialCache();

        cc.Add(new Uri(MessageApiString), "NTLM", new NetworkCredential("AC4840da0d7************f98b20b084", "f7fc2**************75342"));

        request.Credentials = cc;

        request.Method = "POST";

        var result = request.GetResponse();
```

Still getting 401. Any ideas?

**Update 2**

Alright, thanks to the answers below I was able to get through to the api, but now I'm getting a 400 Bad Request. Is there a cleaner way to build a query string to pass this data along? The three fields are `From`, `To`, and `Body`.

Comment: Did this ever get sovled? I want to do it in the same way

Comment: Let me find out what I did and I'll get back to you!

Comment: could you please look at me question as I got the same issue
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23394895/send-message-using-a-webrequest-and-twilio

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try including

```
 request.Method = "POST";
```

and

```
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
```

Answer (score 2):

The `-u` option in Curl is to [specify a username and password](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html) for Server Authentication.

For C# this is set using the [WebRequest.Credentials](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.credentials.aspx) property.