# equal of php in asp.net

Tags: php, asp.net

what is the equivalent code in asp.net language???

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init("http://irnafiarco.com/queue");
$request["queue"] = file_get_contents("/path_to_my_xml_file/my_xml_file.xml");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $request);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
echo $response;
?>
```

in http://irnafiarco.com/queue a Listener that get requst xml file and saver xml file.

Comment: So, you given us homework!!!!!

Comment: Could you please explain what the code does for us ASP.NET developers.

Comment: @ sikender.no this is a real question

Comment: *(related)* first google serp for "asp.net curl" => http://forums.asp.net/t/788908.aspx/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [WebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.aspx), this will be the basic code

```
   var req = WebRequest.Create(@"http://irnafiarco.com/queue"))

   // prepare the request
   req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
   req.Method = "POST";

   // push the file contents into request body
   var data = "queue=" + System.IO.File.OpenText(filePath).ReadToEnd();
   var bytes = System.Text.Encoding.Ascii.GetBytes(data );  
    request.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
   var rs = req.GetRequestStream();
   rs.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length); 
   rs.Close ();

   // get the response
   var resp = req.GetResponse();
   var sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream());
   var result = sr.ReadToEnd();
```

*Disclaimer: untested code*

**EDIT**:
Added the post parameter name ("queue") which I have missed in first draft. Also added content-length for the request. This code should get you started. The basic idea is you need to simulate exact post request generated by PHP code. Use tool such as Fiddler/ Firebug on FF to inspect & compare request/response from PHP and .NET code.

Further, I suspect that the PHP code may generating request with content type as `multipart/form-data`. However,  I believe that server should also able to support the post body with `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` (because we have only one parameter in body) but in case it doesn't work and you must generate POST body as `multipart/form-data` then it will be little more involved. See this SO question where accepted answer has given the sample code for the same : [Upload files with HTTPWebrequest (multipart/form-data)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/566462/upload-files-with-httpwebrequest-multipart-form-data)

Comment: @GodIsLive, corrected the code and also see my edit in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [WebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5t9y35bd%28vs.71%29.aspx), WebProxy [classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webproxy.aspx) which are inline with what you're after...

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);
request.Proxy = new WebProxy("http://blahblahblah", true)
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
// handle response here
```

Also, [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/381596/asp-equivalent-of-curl-not-asp-net), [and here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7507612/asp-net-equivalent-to-this-curl-command), though may not be relevant for your implementation

Examples of using these to fetch XML abound, i.e.:

```
System.Net.HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)System.Net.WebRequest.Create("yourURL.xml");
webRequest.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
webRequest.Accept = "text/xml";
System.Net.HttpWebResponse webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse();
System.IO.Stream responseStream = webResponse.GetResponseStream();
System.Xml.XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(responseStream);
//Do something meaningful with the reader here
reader.Close();
webResponse.Close();
```

Comment: if response have a xml file how handle this